# Say What Puzzle from Magazine

Tags: rebus

What words/phrase does the following rebus represent?:

> **+ DEEF**

The answer is two words, each containing 8 letters.

Comment: HI, welcome to Puzzling Stackexchange! Unfortunately, this puzzle seems to be too broad of a question, do you think you can elaborate or add on to the question? Also, I'm not too sure if this constitutes as a rebus puzzle.

Comment: It's fine. It's a rebus, it just so happens the picture can be rendered in ASCII.

Comment: ? Really? I thought rebuses had to have pictures or words that represent pictures. Would this constitute better as wordplay or no?

Comment: @Mavis - Welcome to PSE. Since you've sourced this puzzle from elsewhere, can you provide details of the source (to avoid running afoul of plagiarism rules). If it's from a magazine, the name/issue should be sufficient.

Answer (score 26):

It is

> Positive Feedback

Because

> It is the word feed, backwards and a "+" meaning positive.